# compiling c++ projects with sln file in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, compilation, sln-file

This may be a stupid question, but I've been trying to compile a larger project that was originally associated with visual studio in Ubuntu. I settled on cmake to do this, but it needs a cmakelist file. As I don't want to set this up manually, since I'll have to port several thousand pages like this, is there a way to have cmake read the sln files visual studio generates?

Any way that would let me compile the projects automatically on Ubuntu would be great.

Comment: There used to be a tool for this however in the long run it's was better to just create a CMakeLists yourself. See `Converters from other buildsystems to CMake` here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/home